# how to link files to checkboxes?

Tags: file, checkbox, linker, task, inno-setup

I'm having some problems with my check-boxes I use a custom skin and create my own check-boxes
so the problem is I have my check-box and I would like it to open readme.txt cant seem to achieve this the my check-boxes do show up but cant seem to get it linked to the read-me file Ive  tried my different ways but I am stumped. Below is where i have my readme files in  the code trying to get it to work under "files" it does work but not with my check-box auto open also tried run dont know what to do. i have not tried IsTaskSelected():

```
[Files]
//runs after clicking finished now matter what
Source: "README.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme;

[Components]
Name: "Readme"; Description: "Readme"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: StartAfterInstall; Description: Run application after install
Name: "Readme"; Description: "Readme";   

var
DirectXCB,VisualCCB,NvidiaPhysx,Framework,UE4Editor,Readme,IconCB: TNewCheckBox;

//create my checkbox
Readme := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
with Readme do
begin
Parent := WizardForm;
Left := (30);
Top :=(300);
Width := ScaleX(255);
Height := ScaleY(17);
Caption := 'Readme';
end;

Procedure HideComponents();
begin
    Readme.Show;
end;

//not needed for readme checkbox to show up maybe link to readme.txt somehow??
if CurStep=ssPostInstall then begin
if Readme.Checked then begin
Status.Caption:='read me ...';
Status.Left := 120;
Status.Top := 200;
Status.Width := 227;
Status.Height := 20;
Exec2(ExpandConstant('{src}\Redist\Readme.txt'),'/silent',false);
end;
end;
if (CurStep=ssInstall) and ISDoneError then begin
Exec2(ExpandConstant('{uninstallexe}'), '/VERYSILENT', false);
end;
end;

//--------  Third page  --------\\
if CurPageID=wpSelectTasks then begin
HideComponents;
WizardForm.Position:=poScreenCenter;
WizardForm.Caption:= 'Select Tasks «{#AppName}»';
WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Show;
WizardForm.Bevel1.hide;
Bevel3.Hide;
Bevel4.Hide;
Bevel5.Hide;
Bevel6.Hide;
//change last four to show
Bevel20.hide;
Bevel21.hide;
Bevel22.hide;
Bevel23.hide;
WizardForm.ComponentsList.Show;
WizardForm.TasksList.Show;
DirectXCB.Show;
DirectXCB.Checked:= True;
VisualCCB.Hide;
VisualCCB.Checked:= False;
NvidiaPhysx.Checked:= False;
NvidiaPhysx.Enabled:= False;
NvidiaPhysx.hide;
Framework.Show;
Framework.Enabled:= True;
Framework.Checked:= True;


//for read me to show up
Readme.Enabled:= True
Readme.Show
Readme.Checked:= True
IconCB.show;
IconCB.Checked:= True;
TasksBevel.Hide;
TasksLbl.Show;
WizardForm.NextButton.Caption:='Install';
TasksSeparateBevel.hide;
end;
```

Comment: You need to give some details before jumping right into the problem. I see you're creating an Inno installer, but it would help to say that before jumping into your checkbox issue. Also, see if you can reduce this code dump to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).